# What can make a Win32 C++ pointer that doesn't change address suddenly point to invalid memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, access-violation, heap-corruption

I have a C++ program with a memory corruption problem that I am currently debugging inside Visual Studio 2013.  I am using gflags to help pinpoint the problem:

https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/1j9/gflags-a-debugging-story.html

I have all the DLLs the app pulls in as part of the gflags command line too.

I'm a veteran C++ programmer and have dealt with pointer problems many times.  This one is strange to me.  When tracing starts I write down the memory address the pointer is pointing too, the one showing in the Watch window.

When gflags triggers a breakpoint that Visual Studio catches, I am surprised to discover that the memory pointer is still pointing to the exact same address.  However, **now** the Watch window shows the memory area the pointer pointing to as being invalid ("Error reading characters at...").  Since the Exception being triggered is an access violation (*c0000005*) I have to assume that the memory the pointer to is pointing to is considered "*outside the current process*".  The reason I say that is if it were merely a matter of the memory area being deallocated or freed improperly, the address would still point to an area of memory within the current process space, and shouldn't trigger an access violation.  It would simply be pointing to random content.

In other words, this isn't the usual case of the pointer address itself getting corrupted or overwritten causing the pointer to point to memory outside the current process space.  The original address of the pointer never changes from the time that it is allocated.

What can cause a pointer whose memory address doesn't change, and starts out pointing to valid memory within the process space, suddenly be pointing to memory considered invalid to the point of triggering a system access violation?  Also, what's the best way to try and debug the problem?

Comment: It seems fairly obvious that something deallocated that memory...

Comment: Maybe returning the address of a local variable?  It's just guessing until we get an idea of what the function you're calling actually does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Unlikely since I don't think stack space is ever deallocated (unless the thread exits). But large heap allocations might do that, or memory-mapped files.

Comment: `if it were merely a matter of the memory area being deallocated or freed improperly, the address would still point to an area of memory within the current process space, and shouldn't trigger an access violation` That assumption is wrong. Memory that was freed by the process (e.g. VirtualFree) *will* trigger an access violation.

Comment: Another possibility: the pointer used to point to a global variable or a function in a DLL, and that DLL got unloaded.

Comment: @dxiv - If you are so inclined, please upgrade your comment to a full answer and I will accept it.  Once I saw your comment, I started debugging with that in mind and later found the problem.  It turned out it was a thread conflict with one thread freeing a shared buffer while another thread was still using it.  That assumption of mine, which you corrected in your comment, kept me from looking in certain places and doing certain tests, and that kept me from finding the problem at first.

Comment: Good to know that you figured it out. Mine was a pointer at best, the answer is yours for writing if you so choose.

Comment: @dxiv Ok.  I'll add it as a wiki/community answer and credit your comment.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a thread conflict with one thread freeing a shared memory buffer that another was still using.  Thanks to the comment made by @dxiv where he corrected my perception about access violations, I was able to hunt down the problem.

I had thought (*wrongly) *that the only way a pointer could **trigger an access violation** was if the pointer itself was corrupted and was set to memory that was outside it's process space, either by the assignment of an invalid address or by the pointer being corrupted by being overwritten accidentally.  Instead, as dxiv pointed out, an *access violation* can also be triggered if the memory a pointer is pointing to is released (freed) and the pointer is subsequently accessed.

Armed with that new knowledge and the *gflags* utility, I found where the first thread was freeing the shared memory buffer and fixed the problem.